# Disable unobtrusive validation for dropdownlistfor postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a View, and all fields data depends of my DropDownListFor selected item. But the problem is when I change the DropDownListFor Index I only need to refresh my view with the new data, but the unobtrusive validation send to me all the messages like "the x field is required"

This is my DropDownListFor

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Perfil_ID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Perfil_ID", "Nombre"), new
            {
                id = "myddl",
                onchange = "submit(); "

            })%>
```

Is there a way to make the DropDownListFor postback without the unobtrusive validations? Notice that when I click the submit button directly I need de unobtrusive validation.

Hope you can help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can prevent validation from running by setting

```
$("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
```

Despite the name, this won't prevent the submit from happening. Looking at the jquery-validation code, it appears it simply prevents the calling of `validator.form()`, which is the validation pass.

Note that jquery-validation will set the value back to false afterwards - it only stops validation for one submit (if you end up stopping the submit for some reason).